# Как в c# прочитать байты из файла, «занятого другим процессом»?

Tags: c#

Не получается прочитать байты из файла через `ReadAllBytes`. Файл занят другим процессом. Как все таки как-то получить байты из этого файла? И процесс этот желательно не убивать.

Comment: Если процесс не ваш, и файл открывается не расшареном режиме то ни как

Answer (score 1):

Именно с помощью метода [`ReadAllBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.file.readallbytes(v=vs.90).aspx) не уверен, что можно сделать. А вот немного другим способом сделать можно. Для этого используем [`FileStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx) и [`StreamReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx). У [`FileStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx) ключевым аттрибутом является `FileShare.ReadWrite`. Пример рабочего кода:

```
byte[] bytes;
string text;

using (FileStream stream = File.Open("C:\\test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        // прочитаем весь текст из файла
        text = reader.ReadToEnd(); 
    }
}

// конвертируем строку в массив байт
bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
```

Работоспособность данного подхода проверил. Открыл текстовый документ одновременно в списке программ (Блокнот, Notepad++, WordPad, Word 2016) и запустил программу - прочитал все без ошибок.

Полезные ссылки:

- [How can I read a file even when getting an “in use by another process” exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4400546/5275890)
- [How do you read a file which is in use?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3709300/5275890)
- [Converting string to byte array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16072742/5275890)
- [Класс `StreamReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Метод `StreamReader.ReadToEnd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Блокнот не лочит файл. Лочит - ворд, например.

Comment: @nick_n_a проверил с Notepad++, WordPad и Word - все работает

Comment: Не получается.
System.IO.IOException: "Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу "H:\yyy\BlueStacks\Android\Data.sparsefs\store", так как этот файл используется другим процессом."

Comment: @Mart очень интересно... подозреваю, что процесс блочит все. А обычный текстовый редактор может открыть этот файл? Попробуйте открыть текстовым редактором, пока есть это исключение. И еще, вы указали правильно все аттрибуты? Про `FileShare.ReadWrite` не забыли?

Comment: Обычный текстовый редактор тоже не открывает. Указал все, как вы написали.

Comment: @Mart если даже редактор не открыает, то видимо не получится :(